# Can't remove `console` statements with babel nor terser in vue cli 3 / 4, but second build run works

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli-3, babel-loader, terser

I'm having issues with `npm run build`, which effectively calls `vue-cli-service build`. My goal is to remove `console` statements in production builds. However, the first time it fails. If I run it again immediately (without code changes), it succeeds.

For reproducibility and isolation, I'm running code in a node docker:

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd):/usr/src/app" node:14.4.0 /bin/bash
```

In the docker I setup the environment

```
npm ci
```

In the clean environment, running the build fails:

```
root@bd366b5873ca:/usr/src/app# npm run build

> my-app@0.1.0 build /usr/src/app
> vue-cli-service build

PRODUCTION babel setup
production eslint setup.

⠦  Building for production...production eslint setup.
⠇  Building for production...PRODUCTION babel setup
⠼  Building for production...production eslint setup.
⠙  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 8 errors
```

The errors are all `eslint` errors on occurrences of `console.` commands:

```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: Unexpected console statement (no-console) at XXXX
```

Immediately running the build again, results in a successful build:

```
root@bd366b5873ca:/usr/src/app# npm run build

> my-app@0.1.0 build /usr/src/app
> vue-cli-service build

PRODUCTION babel setup
production eslint setup.

⠏  Building for production...

 WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings
```

The `PRODUCTION babel setup` and `production eslint setup` originate from my `babel.config.js` and `.eslint.rc`.

I've configured `eslint` as follows, to fail on `console.` statements in production:

```
# .eslintrc.js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  console.info('production eslint setup.')
}
module.exports = {
  root: true,

  env: {
    node: true
  },

  'plugins': ['jest'],

  'extends': [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    '@vue/standard',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/style'
  ],

  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off'
  },

  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    parserOptions: {
      babelOptions: {
        configFile: "babel.config.js"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I've configured babel to remove the `console.` statements:

```
# babel.config.js
/* eslint-disable no-var */
module.exports = (api) => {
  var isProd = api.cache.invalidate(() => process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
  var plugins = []
  if (isProd) {
    console.info('PRODUCTION babel setup')
    plugins.push(['transform-remove-console', { exclude: [] }])
  }
  return {
    presets: ['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'],
    plugins
  }
}
```

In attempts to get it fixed, I've also configured `terser` to remove `console.` statements:

```
# vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  'transpileDependencies': [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  publicPath: process.env.PUBLIC_SUB_PATH === ''
    ? '/' : '/' + process.env.PUBLIC_SUB_PATH + '/',
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  css: {
    extract: { ignoreOrder: true }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization.minimize = true
    config.optimization.minimizer('terser').tap((args) => {
      args[0].terserOptions.compress.drop_console = true
      return args
    })
  }
}
```

Versions (from `package.json`). In attempt to fix it, upgraded to vue-cli 4, also happened in vue-cli 3:

```
....
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.3.4",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.1",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
....
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0"
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    ...
}
```

### Question:

The console prints of `PRODUCTION babel setup` and `production eslint setup` show that in a clean build, the configuration is loaded multiple times. Then it fails somehow. Running it again seems more straightforward, configs are loaded once and then it succeeds.

**How can I configure vue to successfully build the first time, removing the console statements?**

---

### Is it the cache?

After the successsful build, removing the cache:

```
rm -Rf ./node_modules/.cache
```

and then building it again (`npm run build`) is equal to the first run: fails

---

### Modern build?

When creating a `modern` build (after a `npm run build` to populate the cache):

```
 npm run build -- --modern
```

Successfully builds the legacy build, but fails the modern build:

```
> my-app@0.1.0 build /usr/src/app
> vue-cli-service build "--modern"

PRODUCTION babel setup
production eslint setup.

⠏  Building legacy bundle for production...

 WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings          

....
PRODUCTION babel setup
production eslint setup.

⠹  Building modern bundle for production...PRODUCTION babel setup
⠧  Building modern bundle for production...PRODUCTION babel setup
⠋  Building modern bundle for production...PRODUCTION babel setup
⠏  Building modern bundle for production...PRODUCTION babel setup
PRODUCTION babel setup
⠹  Building modern bundle for production...PRODUCTION babel setup
⠧  Building modern bundle for production...PRODUCTION babel setup
⠦  Building modern bundle for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors 

Module Error (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):

/usr/src/app/src/axios.js
   7:3  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console
```

Running the modern build again immediately after it succeeds successfully. So I need in total 3 runs for the modern build to succeed (first time legacy bundle fails, second time legacy bundle succeeds but modern build fails, third time legacy and modern build succeed).

### Vue issue

There is a related vue issue at https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5399

Comment: I have the same problem here

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one @ValentinGavran , but unfortunately no solution..

Comment: Linked [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5399) is the key. Problem is caused by some unintended interaction of `eslint-loader` and `cache-loader`. Should be fixed now in Vue CLI v5 (still in alpha stage atm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met the same err and i fixed it through adding `lintOnSave: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` in `vue.config.js`. The following is the checklist to help u fix ur problem:

- `npx vue-cli-service inspect --mode production >> webpack.config.production.js` generate webpack configuration file in production
- then you can see `lint` is before `terser`. It makes the first time `yarn build` failure and the next time is successful
- so in this case, you can turn off the `lintOnSave` in production

About [`lintOnsave`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#lintonsave)

Comment: That indeed seems to mitigate the error.
However, if I understand well, there is no lint checking at all on the production build right?